# linq max inside a "where" clause with an "and" condition too in lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to get a field with those conditions, my actual code in SQL is this:

```
SELECT archivo, fechadiario 
FROM ri_diariodefotos 
WHERE idproyecto=@projectId
AND fechadiario = (SELECT MAX(fechadiario) 
                   FROM ri_diariodefotos 
                   WHERE idproyecto=@projectId)
```

I actually have this :

```
RI_DiariodeFotos.Where(a=> a.Idproyecto == PROJECTID && a.Fechadiario == 
    RI_DiariodeFotos
        .Where(x=> x.Idproyecto == PROJECTID)
        .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Fechadiario)
        .Select(x=> x.Fechadiario)
        .FirstOrDefault())
        .Select(w=> w.Archivo).ToList().First()
```

and it actually works but when i try to i get this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
>   ToListString'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Have you tried removing `.ToList()` altogether? It doesn't seem to be necessary at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you well, you want to get `Max(of Fechadiario)` for each project. So, you need to group data by `projectid`:

```
var result = RI_DiariodeFotos
    .Where(x=> x.Idproyecto==PROJECTID)
    .GroupBy(x=> x.Idproyecto)
    .Select(g=>new
        {
            ProjectId = g.Key,
            Fechadiario = g.Max(f=>f.Fechadiario)
        });
```

**Note:**

To use it with EF, you have to declare class as follow:

```
public class ProjectStatistic
{
   public int ProjectId {get;set;}
   public int Fechadiario {get;set;}
}
```

then you have to "grab" query results into `Enumerable<ProjectStatistic>` by adding `ProjectStatistic` right after `new` keyword in `Select` statement.

Comment: yes you did understand well, but there i need a clause "Where" to filter only the requested project

Comment: thank you very much. I actually had an partial answer but your solution is way better...